# Excel improving date diff function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've defined the following formula in Excel

```
=DATEDIF(B595;TODAY();"y") & " years, " & DATEDIF(B595;TODAY();"ym") & " months, " & DATEDIF(B595;TODAY();"md") & " days"
```

But it shows a result like:

```
0 years, 0 months, 20 days
```

I would prefer to see:

```
20 days
```

Can I use a VBA function to get a nicer result? Or a formula?

Comment: you can use a Formula, a bit long, but just add a few `IF`

Comment: If you are using `DATEDIF`, be sure you understand some of its limitations, especially, if `start_date` is after the 28th of the month.  For example, try it with `31-Jan-2015` to `1-Mar-2015` and the Days output will be a negative number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add If statements to the formula that will remove the component if DateDif evaluates to zero:

```
=IF(DATEDIF(B595;TODAY();"y")=0;"";DATEDIF(B595;TODAY();"y") & " years, ") & _
 IF(DATEDIF(B595;TODAY();"ym")=0;"";DATEDIF(B595;TODAY();"ym") & " months, ") & _
 IF(DATEDIF(B595;TODAY();"md")=0;"";DATEDIF(B595;TODAY();"md") & " days, ")
```

I broke the formula into three lines so its readable here, but it should be inputted as one line

Comment: Thanks! ps: there is a small mistake in the formula the comma should be semicolumn

Comment: @Revious ahh careless mistake on my part.  Forgot about the regional differences (the bane of my existence working with excel!)